# Google Sheets Script: Cannot Add or Delete Project Properties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Project Properties in my attached script to store user settings. The existing properties work OK, they can be retrieved or updated as expected.

However, I cannot Delete obsolete properties, or add a new one, from File > Project Properties. No error messages appear.

When I click "Delete", the property is removed from the list, so it looks like it worked, but when I reopen the properties, they are still there.

Similarly, when I "Add new", it appears to work OK (no err msg), but is not there when I reopen the properties.

Does anyone know if this is some sort of corruption - and if so, how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173495423) with the properties UI. Update your properties programmatically using the [Properties class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) instead.

I've been unable to reliably reproduce the issue, but I have had it happen to me on several occasions.